# How to do subdomain Wordpress sites with pre-existing site

Tags: wordpress

I am installing Wordpress to provide CMS Functionality as a function to my pre-existing site.

I have a current website (www.mywebsite.com) and I'm interested in having several customer specific sites: customer1.mywebsite.com; customer2.mywebsite.com that each have a series of CMS capable features.

If I install WP to a subdomain (wp.mywebsite.com), it seems like I am forced to use sub-subdomains (customer1.wp.mywebsite.com).

If I install WP to a subdirectory, it seems like I can't have subdomains setup.

If Install over my root, it deletes my website.

Is there a solution that would allow me to do:

- http://www.mywebsite.com ... my preexisting website
- customer1.mywebsite.com ... customer1's cms
- customer2.mywebsite.com ... customer2's cms

I don't have a preference where the root WP instance's URL is located.

Hosting on iis7

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: You can absolutely install Wordpress in a subdirectory and have that point to subdomain.  What hosting do you use?  Do they have cpanel?

Comment: Since you're using IIS, can't you simply create a new Website for each customer, and then use Hostnames/DNS to route to those 'subsites'?

Comment: @Chris & Calvin, I think you both have the same idea and that's a good one.  I was trying to solve the problem inside of wordpress but I think iis handling it would be easier/better.